# Link to Skeptics in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request

We have a link to Genealogy in the What Can I Ask Here? -> This is Not About, but we don't have a link the Skeptics on the Conspiracy theories bullet. Should we add it to keep consistant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not a bad idea, I'm a big fan of consistency...when we can be consistent.  I'll make the update.

Comment: Hm, did you happen to check with the Skeptics mods? Not so sure they'd want their site advertised as a site about conspiracy theories...