# Link to Mythology.SE in the Tour

Tags: feature-request, on-topic, hyperlinks

The part of the [Tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) that explains what kinds of questions are on-topic here on this site links to Genealogy.SE and Skeptics.SE but not to Mythology.SE:

> [image]

However, in the [Help Center's section on on-topic questions](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), all three sites are linked:

> [image]

So, unless there's a big reason not to, perhaps Mythology.SE could be linked in the tour as well.

(I wouldn't have bothered to post this because of how minor it is, but this [related question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/link-to-skeptics-in-the-faq) convinced me to.)

---

Also, more trivially, the punctuation/capitalization is inconsistent: it says '*pseudoscience*' in the Tour but '*Pseudo-science*' in the Help Center.

Comment: I agree with this in principle. However, I'm afraid I disagree that questions about Mythology should be prima facie off-topic. "What was Hercules' 3rd task?", yeah that's off-topic. But "Was Hercules worshipped in Ctesiphon before Alexander?" seems fine to me. So I guess that's not the edit *I'd* like to make were I to go in there making edits...